# Write "in another format" a default map <String,Integer> by default to Integer 0 and then based on condition count the occurrencies

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a default map of key value given like that

```
 private Map<String, Integer> output = Stream.of(MyEnumCode.values())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.code, e -> 0));//default EN1:0,ENS:0..
```

Note my enum is in this format

```
public enum MyEnum{

EN1("EN1"), ENS("ENS"), ENT("ENT").....;

String code;

MyEnum(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}
```

After that there is a part of code witha  switch statement that based on condition determines the MyEnumCodeValue and  it is reiterated again to count the occurrencies of these enumvalues like that:

```
 output.merge(MyEnumCode.code, 1, Integer::sum); //-->outuput like EN1:3,ENS:1 (based on occurrencies)
```

so by default I read this enumcodes and collect them to a map to output by default by 0.
is there another way to achieve the same result written in another way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the first statement where you are adding all the enum values in the map.

```
private Map<String, Integer> output = Stream.of(MyEnumCode.values())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.code, e -> 0));//default EN1:0,ENS:0..
```

Instead of doing this, you can do something like this.

```
private Map<String, Integer> output = new HashMap<>();
```

and at the time of putting values in the map, you can use,

```
output.put(enumKey, output.getOrDefault(enumKey, 1));
```

But the output can be diff for both the maps. Like this map will contain only those keys that are having occurrence more then one.

**Update:**

```
private Map<String, Integer> output = Stream.of(MyEnumCode.values())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.code, e -> 0));
//Some statements
//....
//....
output.put(enumKey, output.getOrDefault(enumKey, 0) + 1);
```

Here output map will be having occurrence of all the enum keys be it 0 or not 0.

Comment: Thanks but Is still not working that way I need by default all values with a 0 and then after the occurrencies of the codes are calculated I have to sum up them.

Comment: okay, map can't have same keys with diff values. instead of doing merge you can just do simple mathematics. I have updated the ans.

Comment: ok the second part is working other ideas on how to write differently the first part? I upvoted your question for now

Comment: I don’t get it. The `output.merge(MyEnumCode.code, 1, Integer::sum);` of the question does already work correctly, regardless of whether you pre-initialize the mapping with zero or start with an empty map. What is the reason to replace that with an alternative that is more complicated and does not work in all secenarios?